# Percentage calculation poll system mysql different rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table **poll**:

```
id  question  votes  
1   question1  3  
2   question2  4  
3   question3  3
```

I want to calculate the percentage value of the votes rows independently.

This is the code I use:

```
SELECT *,(votes/sum(votes))*100 as perc from poll group by id;
```

When I do this I get for every perc 100%

Then I tried this:

```
SELECT *,(votes/sum(votes))*100 as perc from poll;
```

Then it returns only the first row with the correct percentage value.

Can someone tell me what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the percent of each vote for each question.

Your 
`SELECT *,(votes/sum(votes))*100 as perc from poll group by id;`
doesn't work because it's getting the sum by ID.

So you first must get that sum in a sub query then divide by it.  The problem is an order of operation issue within the query syntax itself.

```
SELECT ID, Question, (votes/B.SV)*100 as perc 
FROM POLL
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(VOTES) SV FROM POLL) B
GROUP BY ID, Question
```

I prefer this approach to a select within the select clause as it only has to do the math once vs every time when a select within a select.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id,
       sum(votes) * 100 / (select count(*) from poll) as perc 
from poll 
group by id
```

Comment: I get a 100+ value out of this calculation. 
I want for every row the percentage value.

Answer (score 0):

The total (`SUM()`) of votes represents 100%. So using the [croos-multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication), this query is what you need:

```
SELECT votes*100/SUM(votes) perc
FROM poll
```

Comment: this returns only the first row with the correct percentage.
I want it for all 3 questions.